# Printing multiple database entries with the same name

Tags: python, loops

sorry, i'm not too sure how to phrase this question.
I am making a database of herbs to be used in cooking etc. and using a python scrip to search the database.

Basically i have multiple entries in the database that have the same name or similar (such as Siberian ginseng and panax ginseng). I would like to print out all of the entries that have the name in them (eg. ginseng), but am not sure how.

this is my code so far:

```
while True:

    herb=input("Herb: ")

    database=open("db.txt")

    for line in database:
        record = line.split('|')
        if record[0] == herb:
            found = True
            break
        else:
            found = False
            continue

    if found == False:
        print("No herbs in database.")
        print('')
    else:
        print(record[0]) 
        print(record[1]) 
        print(record[2]) 
        print(record[3])
        print('')
```

The output only displays the first entry that has the herb (ginseng) in it, however i want all entries that have the name anywhere in it to be displayed.
Apologies if this question has already been answered or i haven't phrased it right.

Comment: A database and a pure text file are a bit different things. Any reason you aren't using a database like SQLite? Then you can very easily query for the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your iterating over your records and when you find an entry that matches you break out of the loop and print it right away.

Something you might want to do is to make a printHerbs function which takes the record array and prints it when its found and not break the loop.

Also only display not found if they reach the end of the loop an nothing was found. It might look something like this:

```
herb=input("Herb: ")

database=open("db.txt")

def printHerbs(record):
    print(record[0]) 
    print(record[1]) 
    print(record[2]) 
    print(record[3])
    print('')

found = False;
for line in database:
    record = line.split('|')
    if herb.lower() in record[0].lower():
        found = True
        printHerbs(record)

if found == False:
    print("Herb not found in database")
```

Also if you are trying to match if a string is a substring of another string you can use:

```
if "Ginsing" in "Ginsing Tea":
    print("Found")
```

The .lower() method will make sure both strings are lowercase when they are being compared.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `if herb in record[0]` condition (and probably also case insensitive). It should match "ginseng" in "siberian ginseng".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes, sorry i wasn't exactly clear, but it works well, thank you!